# How to filter queryset with one lookup field on mutiple fields in django-filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Lets say I have 2 fields `["id", "name"]`.
I want to filter my queryset in my `ModelViewSet` by using `django-filter`.

Here is my custom `FilterSet`:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from store.models import Partner


class PartnerFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    """ Custom Partner Filter Set """

    name = filters.CharFilter(field_name="name", lookup_expr="icontains")

    class Meta:
        model = Partner
        fields = ["id", "name"]
```

And This is my `ModelViewSet`:

```
class PartnerViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """ Partner View Set """

    serializer_class = PartnerSerializer
    queryset = Partner.objects.select_related("user").all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,]
    filterset_class = PartnerFilter
```

What I need is to filter queryset by using only one **query string**. I don't want my url to be like `.../?id=&name=string`.

I want something like that:
`.../?search=search_value` and if it matches any `id` then it gets the object by **id** or if it matches with `name` then it gets object by **name**.

How can I implement this in `django-filter`?
Is there a way to do it without overriding `get_queryset` method in `ModelViewSet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `django-filter` for that, what you actually need is [SearchFilter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter)

Your view should look something like this:

```
from rest_framework import filters


class PartnerViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """ Partner View Set """

    serializer_class = PartnerSerializer
    queryset = Partner.objects.select_related("user").all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['id', 'name']  # add here any other field that you want to match your search
```

After adding this you can use your endpoint with `.../?search=search_value`